# PHP function with parameters to update all columns in MySQL table but don't require all parameters and don't always update all columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with columns:

```
opID, opDateAdded, opLastUpdated, opUser, opPropertySaleID, opArray, refurbID, opRefurbCost, opViewingArranged, opOfferAccepted, opOfferAcceptedID, opPaon, opStreet, opPostcode, opPropertyType, opViewingDate, opViewingBy, opViewingPersonName, opFloorArea, opBedrooms, opBathrooms, opReceptions, opAskingPrice, opValuation, opOptMatchingBedrooms, opOptMatchingBuild, opOptMatchingType, opOptSimilarFloor, opOptDistance, opLatitude, opLongitude, opNotes
```

I want to have one function that allows me to update the columns of this table but sometimes only 3-4 columns will need updating, not always all of them.

I'm just wondering what the best method of approaching this is?

I could create a function like:

```
function updateOpportunity($opID, $opDateAdded, $opLastUpdated, $opUser, $opPropertySaleID, $opArray, $refurbID, $opRefurbCost, $opViewingArranged, $opOfferAccepted, $opOfferAcceptedID, $opPaon, $opStreet, $opPostcode, $opPropertyType, $opViewingDate, $opViewingBy, $opViewingPersonName, $opFloorArea, $opBedrooms, $opBathrooms, $opReceptions, $opAskingPrice, $opValuation, $opOptMatchingBedrooms, $opOptMatchingBuild, $opOptMatchingType, $opOptSimilarFloor, $opOptDistance, $opLatitude, $opLongitude, $opNotes) {
   //update
}
```

And set them as optional then check if they're set or not, if they are then update those rows (using IFNULL in MySQL)

Or maybe it's better and tidier to create a property class and pass in a property:

```
function updateOpportunity($property) {
   //update
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is a standard for creating a function to update a large set of columns that aren't always in need of updating at the same time.

Comment: Which database API are you using? MySQLi, PDO?

Comment: Instead of using multiple parameters use associate array and only update that column which is set in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a generic function which works for all table and column.. like this.

```
function update($table, $data, $id)
{

    $set= array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $set[] = "{$key} ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."'";

    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET ".implode(', ', $set)." WHERE ID = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

}
```

here is a function using a prepared statement.

```
function update($table, $data, $id)
    {

         $setPart = array();
         $bindings = array();

         foreach ($data as $key => $value)
         {
            $setPart[] = "{$key} = :{$key}";
            $bindings[":{$key}"] = $value;
         }

          $bindings[":id"] = $id;

          $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET ".implode(', ', $setPart)." WHERE ID = :id";
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute($bindings);

    }
```

Here the $connection is a mysqli_connection object which we need to create to execute any query to know about this [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp).

and in second function $pdo is PDO connection object which we need to create to execute the query [click here](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/ref.pdo.htm) for more information.

You can read this [link](https://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/time-saving-database-functions) for more information.

to prevent SQL injection you can use  mysqli_real_escape_string() function 
 [click here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) for more information.

Comment: What about using a prepared statement?

Comment: Its also fine but as a programmer, i should suggest writing a code which is reusable.

Comment: Uh, you can re-use prepared statements. Also, `$link` is undefined in your answer.

Comment: @joy Could you do that as a MySQL prepared statement please

Comment: @Scoop its connection object which we pass while running query

Comment: @Scoop I have added the link so you can get more detail of this code

Comment: from where you are getting `$connection` ?

Comment: @joy Works great, thank you. Almost ready to accept answer. One final thing... security? This answer leaves the query vulnerable to SQL injection? Could you update answer to escape such attacks and I'll accept answer. Thanks

Comment: @Scoop for that you can use mysqli_real_escape_string()  .. check updated answer

Comment: @joy A function wouldn't work within that single quote will it?

Comment: @Scoop ohh yes ... updated my answer .. please review.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a class.

```
class Table {
    private $pdo;
    private $table;
    private $where;
    private $key;
    private $id;
    private $values;
    private $sql;

    public function __construct($pdo, $table = null, $key = null, $where = array(), $id = null) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->table($table);
        $this->values($values);
        $this->key($key);
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function table($table) {
        $this->table = $table;
        return $this;
    }

    public function where($where) {
        $this->where = $where;
        $this->id    = null;
        return $this;
    }

    public function key($key) {
        $this->key   = $key;
        return $this;
    }

    public function id($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->where = array();
        return $this;
    }

    private function resetValues() {
        $this->values = array();
        return $this;
    }

    private function getWhere() {
         $where  = '';
         $comma  = ' WHERE ';
         foreach ($this->where as $key => $value) {
            $where  .= $comma . $key . '=?';
            $values[] = $value;
            $comma = ',';
         }
         if ($this->id) {
             if (!$this->key) {
                 throw new \Exception('primary key required but not specified');
             }
             $where  .= $comma . $key . '=?';
             $values[] = $value;
             $comma = ',';
         }
         return $where;
    }

    private function getWhat(&$values) {
         $fields = '';
         $comma  = '';

         foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $fields  .= $comma . $key . '=?';
            $values[] = $value;
            $comma = ',';
         }
         return $fields;
    }

    public function update(array $values) {
         $this->sql  = "UPDATE {$this->table} SET ";
               . $this->resetValues()->getWhat()
               . $this->getWhere();
         return $this;
    }

    public function perform() {
         // Check $this->sql exists ecc.
         return $this->pdo->prepare($this->sql)->execute($this->values());
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
$TUsers = new Table($pdo);
$TUsers->table('users')->key('user_id');

...
$TUsers->update(['name' => 'Leonardo'])->id(137)->perform();
```

Note that the class user does not know which DB interface the class is using - you could offload it via subclassing, by abstracting the connection interface (here the $pdo supplied to the constructor) and the actual execution (here `perform()`).

If needed you might want to cache the prepared statement by comparing the MD5 of the actual SQL (which contains no column values) against a LRU array of saved statements (I believe that PDO might already do that, though). If the statement isn't present in the cache then you prepare() it, otherwise you fetch it back from the cache:

```
private function getStatement() {
    $key = md5($this->sql);
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->stmtCache)) {
        // Expunge the oldest or least used or less costly or...
        // statement  if cache is full - TODO
        // ...
        $this->stmtCache[$key] = [
            'stmt' => $this->pdo->prepare($this->sql)
        ];
    }
    $this->stmtCache[$key]['ts'] = time();
    return $this->stmtCache[$key]['stmt'];
}
```

The same class could be extended with methods such as INSERT, DELETE, SELECT etc., or ancillary functions such as ORDER, GROUP and so on. *And* it could run consistency checks on its data and/or UTF-8 clean your fields and/or log every query matching some specifications, and so on and so forth.

You could also look into [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/).